# Como pasar datos de una vista a otra con Vue y axios en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy trabajando con Laravel y tengo este enlace en la vista A

```
<div id="app">
    <a href="{{ route('ministries.index') }}">Enlace</a>
</div>
```

y quiero que al hacer click sobre ese enlace lo dirija a la vista B y me muestre los resultados obtenidos por el controlador.

Esta es la ruta que tengo:

```
Route::resource('ministries', 'Admin\MinistryController');
```

Codigo de Vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ministries: []
    },
    created: function() {
        this.getMinistries()
    },
    methods: {
        getMinistries: function() {
            var url= 'ministries';
            axios.get(url).then(response => {
                this.ministries = response.data
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Codigo del controlador:

```
public function index() {
    return Ministry::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
}
```

El HTML de la vista B

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="ministry in ministries">
        <td>@{{ ministry.id }}
        <td>@{{ ministry.name }}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso sí es necesario que el controlador entregue una vista como respuesta (la vista B):

```
public function index()
{
    $variable = Modelo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('vista', compact('variable'));
}
```

En cuanto a Vue, no es necesario usar axios (el cual se utiliza para hacer solicitudes Ajax), pues obtienes los datos directamente de Laravel, y tienes la información disponible en blade, simplemente agregas el modelo al objeto data, el cual tiene reactividad, todo esto siempre y cuando no estés usando componentes (según tu sintaxis, no pareciera):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ministries: {!! $variable !!}
    },
});
```

El template se mantendría como lo tienes:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="ministry in ministries">
        <td>@{{ ministry.id }}</td>
        <td>@{{ ministry.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Y que cambiaría si utilizara un componente? planeaba hacerlo así después.

Comment: Si usaras un componente en un archivo externo (.vue), sí podría ser una buena idea usar axios y solicitudes ajax, pero entonces no pasarías la colección de modelos a la vista, pues sería un poco redundante, la solicitud ajax iría a otra ruta, y esa ruta entregaría el json.

Comment: de echo es mas facil con pops y vue router para navegar entre componentes y pasar variables entre los mismos sin llegar a utilizar axios solo salvo ciertas cosas, pero llege tarde :(

Answer (score 0):

Excelente la respuesta sugerida por Shaz, solo haría una pequeña adición a su respuesta y es que los datos deben enviarse desde el controlador en formato json o cuando lo reciba el objeto data de vue pasarlo así:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ministries: {!! json_encode($variable) !!}
  },
});
```